# Dash documentation page: markdown link reloads whole dashboard inside html.IFrame

Tags: python, html, plotly, markdown, plotly-dash

I am working on a `dash` dashboard. Currently I am going to add a documentation section.
I write the documentation as markdown (`info.md`), then I copy and paste its content in Jupyter Notebook (in a cell set as Markdown) in order to download the file as html (`info.html`). Finally I read this file in Python and store its content in a string (`info`).
In the dashboard there are two `dbc.Tabs`, in the second one (`'Page 2'`) I placed a `html.IFrame` with which I display the `info` string content. It gives me this page:

[image]

Within the documentation there is a index with some links. Ideally, these link would direct the user to the sub-section of the documentation. However, when I click on a link the whole dashboard is realoded inside the `html.IFrame` and I get this:

[image]

If I try to re-click on a link, nothing happens.
How can I avoid this nested-reloading inside the `html.IFrame`? When I click on a Index link I simply would like to be re-directed to that content inside the documentation page.

Here the code of the dashboard:

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

info_file = r'info.html'
with open(info_file, encoding = 'utf-8') as file:
    info = ''.join(file.readlines())

app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

app.layout = html.Div(id = 'general_div',
                      children = [html.Div(id = 'title_div',
                                           children = [html.H2(children = 'Title',
                                                               style = {'width': '100%',
                                                                        'text-align': 'center'})]),

                                  dbc.Tabs(children = [dbc.Tab(label = 'Page 1',
                                                               children = [html.P('Some text here')]),

                                                       dbc.Tab(label = 'Page 2',
                                                               children = html.Iframe(srcDoc = info,
                                                                                      style = {'display': 'block',
                                                                                               'box-sizing': 'border-box',
                                                                                               'horizontal-align': 'center',
                                                                                               'width': '100%',
                                                                                               'height': 850}))])])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Here the markdown file:

```
## Index

1. [Chapter 1](#Chapter-1)
   1. [Part 1](#Part-1)
   2. [Part 2](#Part-2)
2. [Chapter 2](#Chapter-2)
   1. [Part 1](#Part-1)


## Chaper 1

### Part 1

### Part 2 

## Chapter 2

### Part 1
```

I would report the html file, but it is way to long (over 13k lines), so I report here only the `<body>` part. In any case, in order to generate the whole html file, it is possible to copy and paste the markdown file in a Jupyter Notebook markdown cell and download the notebook as a html file as I currently do.

```
<body>
  <div tabindex="-1" id="notebook" class="border-box-sizing">
    <div class="container" id="notebook-container">

<div class="cell border-box-sizing text_cell rendered"><div class="prompt input_prompt">
</div><div class="inner_cell">
<div class="text_cell_render border-box-sizing rendered_html">
<h2 id="Index">Index<a class="anchor-link" href="#Index">&#182;</a></h2><ol>
<li><a href="#Chapter-1">Chapter 1</a><ol>
<li><a href="#Part-1">Part 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#Part-2">Part 2</a></li>
</ol>
</li>
<li><a href="#Chapter-2">Chapter 2</a><ol>
<li><a href="#Part-1">Part 1</a></li>
</ol>
</li>
</ol>
<h2 id="Chaper-1">Chaper 1<a class="anchor-link" href="#Chaper-1">&#182;</a></h2><h3 id="Part-1">Part 1<a class="anchor-link" href="#Part-1">&#182;</a></h3><h3 id="Part-2">Part 2<a class="anchor-link" href="#Part-2">&#182;</a></h3><h2 id="Chapter-2">Chapter 2<a class="anchor-link" href="#Chapter-2">&#182;</a></h2><h3 id="Part-1">Part 1<a class="anchor-link" href="#Part-1">&#182;</a></h3>
</div>
</div>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

**EDIT**

I checked the `html.IFrame` [documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-html-components/iframe) and I tried to use the `sandbox` parameter:

```
...
children = html.Iframe(srcDoc = info,
                       sandbox = '',
                       style = {'display': 'block',
                                'box-sizing': 'border-box',
                                'horizontal-align': 'center',
                                'width': '100%',
                                'height': 850})
...
```

This avoids the re-loading of the whole dashboard inside the `html.IFrame`; however, when I click on a link, the `html.IFrame` content becomes empty, it appears a `Loading...` label and nothing happens...

[image]

Comment: Why dont you just use the MarkDown component?

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I already tried it. In the documentation I need to write some LaTeX formulas (as example `c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}`) and, unfortunately, PyCharm (the IDE I use) do not manage to render properly these LaTeX equations...

Comment: Of course I am very interested in any suggestion to simplify the working process I described above (Markdown file → Jupyter Notebook → html file → Python string → `html.IFrame`).